# 'or' statement in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a file I am looking at, I saw a `||` statement in a javascript function call what does it mean?

```
createObject(a_variable || b_variable)
```

Does the function take in a true/false value or it take in something else?

is the above code equivalent to

```
createanotherObject(a_variable ? a_variable : b_variable)
```

Which I saw right next to it.

Comment: That's a form of [logical disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. They both do almost exactly the same thing (the first one is *slightly* more efficient). It'll pass the first truthy value (or the last one - if none are truthy).

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var argument = a_variable;

if ( ! argument ) argument = b_variable;

createObject( argument );
```

Comment: interesting I thought that since it's a logical operation it will evaluate to true or false depend on the variables.

Comment: @user1655072 - Some languages (like PHP) work like that. In JavaScript, [the first truthy value will be returned](http://jsfiddle.net/XcZ8U/) (or the last one).

Answer (score 1):

it will pass the value of `a_variable` if `a_variable` is truethy, else it will pass the value of `b_variable`.

```
var a = false, b = "FOOBAR";
console.log(a || b); // FOOBAR
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, they're the same. It's a short circuit operator, i.e. the second variable is not evaluated if the first is true. It's like

```
a = b || c;

if b is truthy
  a = b
else
  a = c
```

Note: People forget, but 0 is also a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to your second example.  The || (or) condition ends once one of the terms evaluates to a "truthy" value.  If a_variable is null, it will use b_variable.